# why downloading speed drastically getting decreased using cuteftp 8.0

Tags: ftp, sftp

while downloading large number of Files nearly around of (7000 to 10000) with the help of Cute Ftp, downloading time is taking long time per file by file, when i started the my service files are downloading 1kb file per second..slowly it has comes per minute only 2 or 3 three files

while uploading files i have not facing any issue, all of my file will be around of 1KB size files.

please find MY cute ftp settings which i have configured:

transfer settings under global options

--> In transfer window

- transfer mode is : AutoDetect
- data Mode is     : AUTO
- **uncheck** for allow transfers to occur the existing (browse) session
- **CHECKED**  send REST Command prior to APPE when resume a transfer
- when selecting max in a multi-part transfer is default value as 4
  threads

--> IN transfer/events window

***Checked for below options***

Removed successful transfer items from the queue automatically
preserve remote time stamp for the downloaded files

**unchecked for remaining options**

--> In General/log files window

***Checked for below options***

- Delete saved logs every **5 minutes**
- delete error logs after existing the transfer engine
- delete item logs of successful transfer immediately after completion

uncheck for the

- record/display time stamp

when the transfer engine exits : **Delete images in thumbnail cache**

please ask me if any information i need to provide, kindly guide me for to improving the performance speed for downloading transfers

Answer (score 0):

thats just normal, it has to write each file into a sector and special stuff for individual files, unlike big files where the data part is seamless,

if ftp server has a online panel or something similar (for me i have godaddy) that you can compress it all into a zip file, then you can download the zip file at a fast speed. that is what i do